# AS3 trouble instantiating Document Class of loaded SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, loader, document-class

I am loading one swf into another using the Loader class, but when the child swf finishes loading and is added to the display list, its Document Class is not instantiated. I have a few trace statements that should execute when the object is created, but nothing is happening when loaded into the parent SWF. When I compile the child SWF on its own, the Document Class runs as expected.

So I'm wondering... how do I associate a child SWF's Document Class with `Loader.content`?

Code updated with a solution from Kishi below.

```
public class Preloader extends Sprite {
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    // code in parent SWF's Document Class (Preloader.as)
    private var swfLoader:Loader;
    public var mainMovie:MovieClip;

    public function Preloader(){   
        swfLoader = new Loader();
        swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderDone);
        swfLoader.load(new URLRequest("mainmovie.swf"));
    }

    private function loaderDone(e:Event):void {
        // Cast Loader.content to MovieClip
        mainMovie = MovieClip(swfLoader.content);

        mainMovie.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, mainMovieAddedListener);

        addChildAt(mainMovie, 0);

    }
    private function mainMovieAddedListener(e:Event):void {
       // init() not necessary
    }
}

// MainMovie.as runs after casting swfLoader.content to MovieClip

public class MainMovie extends Sprite {

    public function MainMovie(){
        trace('MainMovie WHATTUP'); 
    }

    public function init():void {
        trace('init'); 
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is *how* you are trying to access the swf instance.

First, the document class instance is referred by *Loader*'s *content* property. You'd reference it like this:

```
var swf:DisplayObject = swfLoader.content;
```

But, even then you'd have to cast the *DisplayObject* either to it's real class (*MainMovie*, in this case) or a dynamic class (such as *MovieClip*), as you are trying to use a custom property, that's not part of *DisplayObject* itself. Therefore, you could call *MainMovie.init()* like so:

```
var swf:MovieClip = MovieClip(swfLoader.content);
swf.init();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the mainMovie to stage, then you add a listener which inites it. The event is not fired as it's added after the movie is on stage.

Answer (score 0):

What Cristi said is probably right, for the reason your init method isn't firing, but the more strange issue is that your loaded child swf's Constructor, *MainMovie*, should be firing as soon as that object is created.

Whenever I've done things like this, I've never created a new Sprite object from the contents of the loaded swf. Seems what you're doing there is using the swf like it's BitmapData, to create the Sprite *mainMovie*.

Try this: remove your statement that says `swfLoader = null`, and instead say `addChild(swfLoader);`. If you still want that event listener checking for it being added to the stage, put it before you do the `addChild(swfLoader);`, and of course put it on the *swfLoader* not the *mainMovie* object:

```
swfLoader.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, mainMovieAddedListener);
addChild(swfLoader);
```

See what you get then. [also can you paste the exact error you got from trying to access init?]

debu